# Creating a TabBar segue to another tab via Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have found multiple questions related to creating the `prepareForSegue` method and all that. What I am a bit lost on is how do I create a segue from say my first tab to the second.

Do I create it like I create a segue with a button. I tried starting the CTRL + Drag to the other view, but nothing seemed to highlight? I have a:

```
Tab Bar Controller -> Tide Detail View + Tide Table View
```

I cant seem to find any results on creating that segue ID via the Storyboard. Is the segue between the tabs built in due to the nature or a `UITabBar`

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with trying to segue between tabs of a tab bar controller is that segues are expected to be to new view controllers not existing view controllers. There is no built-in way of using segues to switch tabs.

The standard way of switching tabs is to set `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex`.

Not happy with this option, I created [`JLTTabSegue`](https://github.com/jefferythomas/JLTSegue) as a custom segue to switches between tabs.

Either go the standard route and skip segues altogether, create a custom segue to do it, or try mine if you like.

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks. Maybe I am trying to over engineer what I am doing? I am looking to access an array I set in my ```TideModel``` class and use it in my Tide Table View. On my view I have the JSON request calling and setting the json.